# Need post_type_archive_title function but in 'single'

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, single

I'm trying to pull a custom post type name/title out for use in the breadcrumb of a single-[cpt].php template file.

In the archive-[cpt].php I can use post_type_archive_title() and it echo the name.
How would I get this same title in a single view?

Thanks!

I've trawled though the codex and haven't seen a function, but might have missed it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be one, but the following should work:

```
//Get post type    
$post_type_obj = get_post_type_object( get_post_type() );
//Get post type's label
$title = apply_filters('post_type_archive_title', $post_type_obj->labels->name );        
$archive_title = apply_filters('post_type_archive_title', $post_type_obj->labels->all_items);
```

This can, for instance, be put in one generic `header` template that is applied to all `single-cpt` files. With `is_single()` it can be put in an even more generic `header` template.

For a complete list of labels, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Stephen, yes I know it seems like i should be able to just enter the name manually, but I wanted this template to work across the board for other CPT's too, I should have said that first. Also your solution is still probably what I'll use because it'll pull out the Label so if that ever changes the breadcrumb will reflect that change.